# Unexpected bitmap size after re-sampling a PNG using BitmapFactory.decodeResource()

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a PNG file located in the `res/drawable` folder. Its size is 2524*2524.

Before loading it into an `ImageView`, I would like to resize it according to the dimension of the `ImageView`. So I wrote the following utility code to resize the PNG to a `Bitmap`. (*Slightly modified version of the one from https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html*)

```java
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
        Resources res, int resId, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) {

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, targetWidth, targetHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    Log.d(TAG, "Result bitmap size: " + result.getWidth() + "*" + result.getHeight());
    return result;
}

private static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Target bitmap size: " + targetWidth + "*" + targetHeight);
    int width = options.outWidth;
    int height = options.outHeight;
    Log.d(TAG, "Source bitmap size: " + width + "*" + height);

    int inSampleSize = 1;
    while ((width /= 2) >= targetWidth &&
            (height /= 2) >= targetHeight) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "inSampleSize: " + inSampleSize);
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

In my case, the source PNG image is of **2524*2524**, and the `ImageView` is of **500*500** in **pixel** size. So I am expecting the value of `inSampleSize` to be **4** and the re-sampled bitmap's size to be of **631*631** (2524/4 * 2524/4).

However, the log gives me the following info:

```
D/ImageResizer: Target bitmap size: 500*500
D/ImageResizer: Source bitmap size: 2524*2524
D/ImageResizer: inSampleSize: 4
D/ImageResizer: Result bitmap size: 1656*1656
```

The value of `inSampleSize` is correct. But the result bitmap size is not what I am expecting. 2524 is not even divisible by 1656. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding from resource will unasked adapt image files to gui dimensions.

Better put the file in assets directory.

And use assets manager and decodeFromStream().

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you implied, I tried moving the image to the corresponding dpi folder and the resizing works now.